# How to authenticate AEM APIs?

Tags: security, aem, headless

We are using AEM as content service and exporting AEM content into mobile application. For example below api will be used in mobile application and Mobile application will build the presentation layer.

/content/we-retail/us/en/products/women/shirts/jcr:content/root/content-tile.model.json

Here I basically want to authenticate AEM API before I serve the json response. In essence, I want to only accept requests from mobile applications. I should the request  If anyone else calls AEM. Can anyone tell me what are ways we can protect the AEM APIs

Comment: Do you use AEM as a Cloud Service or on-prem? For Cloud, Adobe has a tutorial for leveraging the Headless functionality that covers authentication https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-with-aem-headless/authentication/service-credentials.html?lang=en

Comment: I am using AMS.  does this feature available in AMS?

Comment: There is a common part in terms of the APIs described there, but the bit where you can esaily generate tokens is part of the cloud offering. AMS may host environments of varying degrees of customization so it's difficult to offer concrete advice without inspecting the architecture of your particular solution.

Comment: If push comes to shove, you can always use the Auth checker and configure the dispatcher accordingly https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/permissions-cache.html?lang=en#:~:text=Dispatcher%20checks%20user's%20access%20permissions,authorization%20for%20the%20requested%20content but I'd speak to an architect within your organization, or the next person closest to one.

Answer (score 0):

At dispatcher level you can add this path accessible for validated user. Mobile application developer pass the credential when they invoke the api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).